# Math random to find Names in an Array while not duplicating

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

So I want to find three names out of an array of names which I then want to write to a new array (not gotten this far yet though), but the problem I have is that it keeps randomizing the same names I already found.

Check out the [jsfiddle script](http://jsfiddle.net/uxd4mzcp/).

Code:

```
findStudentBtn.onclick = findStudent;

function findStudent() {
    var studArray = ["John","Daniel","Hans","Lars","Tom","Amanda","Jane","Sarah"] //1-8
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if (i=1) {
            var randomStud1 = studArray[Math.floor(studArray.length * Math.random())];
            msg8.innerHTML += randomStud1 + ", ";
        }
        if (i=2) {
            var randomStud2 = studArray[Math.floor(studArray.length * Math.random())];
            msg8.innerHTML += randomStud2 + ", ";
        }
        if (i=3) {
            var randomStud3 = studArray[Math.floor(studArray.length * Math.random())];
            msg8.innerHTML += randomStud3 + ", ";
        }

        if (randomStud1 == randomStud2 || randomStud2 == randomStud3 || randomStud1 == randomStud3){
            ms8.innerHTML = "";
            findStudent();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Google how to set the random number generator seed in Javascript- I don't recall offhand but if you're getting the same sequence on each run that'll be the problem.

Comment: A popular approach to "random selection without repetition" is to shuffle the array randomly and then take the first N elements.

Comment: `if (i=1) {` is more an assignment than it is a conditional. You want `if (i === 1){`

Comment: One possibility is always to keep track of the indices you've already chosen and then get another random number if it's the same as any of the indices you've already selected. It's not very elegant but works.

Comment: i've updated the jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/uxd4mzcp/1/, this gives you the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the solution, but not willing to go to the jsfidle, here's is the script I used.

```
findStudentBtn.onclick = function(){
    findStudent();
};

var r_stud = ["John","Daniel","Hans","Lars","Tom","Amanda","Jane","Sarah"];
var r_rndm = [];
var r_newr = [];

function getStudent(){

    //if the amount of available people, is to small to reach 3.
    if(r_rndm.length == r_stud.length){
        //reset the random selected array
        r_rndm = [];
        return r_newr;
    }

    //select a student
    var i_randomStudent = Math.floor(r_stud.length * Math.random());
    var s_randomStudent = r_stud[i_randomStudent];

    if(r_rndm.indexOf(s_randomStudent) >= 0){
        //if it's allready been selected, try again.
        getStudent();
    }else{
        //add students to new selection and to alltime selection
        r_rndm.push(s_randomStudent);
        r_newr.push(s_randomStudent);

        //return the new array
        return r_newr;
    }

};

function findStudent(){

    //reset new array.
    r_newr = [];
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        getStudent();
    };

    //print contents of new array to console.
    console.log(r_newr);

    for(i = 0; i < r_newr.length; i++){
        separator = (i == r_newr.length - 1 && r_rndm.length == 0 ) ? '' : ', ';
        msg8.innerHTML += r_newr[i] + separator;
    }

};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. This is basically what I intended, but I have one question: What does the `r_rndm.indexOf(s_randomStudent) >= 0` line do exactly? Why greater than or equal 0?

Comment: indexOf gives you the index of the first instance of the variable you are checking, in this case, we are looking for the first index of the new name (s_randomStudent) in the array r_rndm. If it is in the array, it will return 0 or something bigger, if it's not it will return -1.

Comment: Thank you very much! You've been very helpful. :)